# Show/Hide input fields based on double radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a possible way that I can target two radio buttons at the same time?

I have two sets of radio buttons, where I want to hide input fields based on the combo selection.

I want to be able to select the Team radio button and the Remote Session button and hide/show inputs fields

Here are the images:

Correct:
[image]

Correct:
[image]

Wrong:
[image]

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('input[name=requestType]').click(function() {
  if(this.value == 'Team')
  {
   $(".total").show();
   $(".teamname").show();
   $(".one").show();
   $(".two").show();
   $(".three").show();
   $(".four").show();
   $(".five").show();
  }
  else
  {
   $(".teams").hide();
  }
 });
```

```html
<form id="form">
 <div class="container form">
 <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="requestType" class="col-form-label">Request Type:</label>
    <label for="singleUser" class="radio-inline"><input id="singleUser" type="radio" name="requestType" value="Single User" checked>Single User</label>
  <label for="teamSelection" class="radio-inline"><input id="teamSelection" type="radio" name="requestType" value="Team">Team</label>
  
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="sessionType" class="col-form-label">Session Type:</label>
    <label for="liveSession" class="radio-inline"><input id="liveSession" type="radio" name="sessionType" value="Live Session" checked>Live Session</label>
  <label for="remoteSession" class="radio-inline"><input id="remoteSession" type="radio" name="sessionType" value="Remote Session">Remote Session</label>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group row requester req">
   <label for="requesterName" class="col-form-label">Requester Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="requesterName" type="text" id="requesterName" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." placeholder="Ex: Jane Doe" required/>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>


 <div class="form-group row teamname teams">
   <label for="teamName" class="col-form-label">Team Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="teamName" type="text" id="teamName" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid team name." placeholder="Ex: PortalHelp Team" required/>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group row teams total">
     <label for="totalUsers" class="col-form-label">Number of Attendees:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="totalUsers">
          <option value="Five" selected>5</option>
          <option value="Six">6</option>
          <option value="Seven">7</option>
          <option value="Eight">8</option>
          <option value="Nine">9</option>
          <option value="Ten">10</option>
        </select>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row one teams">
        <label for="oneUser" class="col-form-label">Names of Attendees:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="oneUser" type="text" id="oneUser" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." placeholder="Ex: John Smith" required/>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

      <div class="form-group row two teams">
        <input class="form-control" name="twoUsers" type="text" id="twoUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
   </div>

      <div class="form-group row three teams">
          <input class="form-control" name="threeUsers" type="text" id="threeUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row four teams">
          <input class="form-control" name="fourUsers" type="text" id="fourUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row five teams">
          <input class="form-control" name="fiveUsers" type="text" id="fiveUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row six teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="sixUsers" type="text" id="sixUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row seven teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="sevenUsers" type="text" id="sevenUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row eight teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="eightUsers" type="text" id="eightUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

   <div class="form-group row nine teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="nineUsers" type="text" id="nineUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row ten teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="tenUsers" type="text" id="tenUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <button type="button" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Submit</button>
          <button type="reset" name="cancelbutton" class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel" onclick="window.location.href='/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/Training.aspx'">Cancel</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: 1. you have to close function with `});`  2. you have add jquery script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function `onclick` `#remoteSession` then check if `Team` is `checked` if yes `hide/show` whatever you want...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('input[name=requestType]').click(function() {
  if(this.value == 'Team')
  {
   $(".total").show();
   $(".teamname").show();
   $(".one").show();
   $(".two").show();
   $(".three").show();
   $(".four").show();
   $(".five").show();
  }
  else
  {
   $(".teams").hide();
     
       
  }
 });
  $('input[name=sessionType]').click(function() {

  if($('input[name=requestType]:checked').val()=='Team' && $('input[name=sessionType]:checked').val()=='Remote Session')
  {
   $(".teams").hide();
    $(".teamname").show();
    
  }
else 
$('input[name=requestType]').click();
  });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
 <div class="container form">
 <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="requestType" class="col-form-label">Request Type:</label>
    <label for="singleUser" class="radio-inline"><input id="singleUser" type="radio" name="requestType" value="Single User" checked>Single User</label>
  <label for="teamSelection" class="radio-inline"><input id="teamSelection" type="radio" name="requestType" value="Team">Team</label>
  
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="sessionType" class="col-form-label">Session Type:</label>
    <label for="liveSession" class="radio-inline"><input id="liveSession" type="radio" name="sessionType" value="Live Session" checked>Live Session</label>
  <label for="remoteSession" class="radio-inline"><input id="remoteSession" type="radio" name="sessionType" value="Remote Session">Remote Session</label>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group row requester req">
   <label for="requesterName" class="col-form-label">Requester Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="requesterName" type="text" id="requesterName" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." placeholder="Ex: Jane Doe" required/>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>


 <div class="form-group row teamname teams">
   <label for="teamName" class="col-form-label">Team Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="teamName" type="text" id="teamName" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid team name." placeholder="Ex: PortalHelp Team" required/>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group row teams total">
     <label for="totalUsers" class="col-form-label">Number of Attendees:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="totalUsers">
          <option value="Five" selected>5</option>
          <option value="Six">6</option>
          <option value="Seven">7</option>
          <option value="Eight">8</option>
          <option value="Nine">9</option>
          <option value="Ten">10</option>
        </select>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row one teams">
        <label for="oneUser" class="col-form-label">Names of Attendees:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="oneUser" type="text" id="oneUser" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." placeholder="Ex: John Smith" required/>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

      <div class="form-group row two teams">
        <input class="form-control" name="twoUsers" type="text" id="twoUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
   </div>

      <div class="form-group row three teams">
          <input class="form-control" name="threeUsers" type="text" id="threeUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row four teams">
          <input class="form-control" name="fourUsers" type="text" id="fourUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row five teams">
          <input class="form-control" name="fiveUsers" type="text" id="fiveUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row six teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="sixUsers" type="text" id="sixUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row seven teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="sevenUsers" type="text" id="sevenUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row eight teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="eightUsers" type="text" id="eightUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

   <div class="form-group row nine teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="nineUsers" type="text" id="nineUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row ten teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="tenUsers" type="text" id="tenUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <button type="button" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Submit</button>
          <button type="reset" name="cancelbutton" class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel" onclick="window.location.href='/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/Training.aspx'">Cancel</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
 Run code snippet
```

Comment: This is working almost perfectly! when I switch back to #liveSession now the inputs don't pop up anymore. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I have tweaked the code a little bit so now it works 100%, but something else is broken :( - I'll create a new question a post it here.